# How to get last full MS SQL Server error message?

Tags: php, sql-server

I am aware of:

```
SELECT @@ERROR
```

but it will give me only an ERROR CODE (a number) and I need a full text message like:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.TABLE_NAME' with unique index 'IX_ID_unique'.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

How can I do that in MS Sql Server 2005 ?

**EDIT:** I need to acquire this error message on Linux and Windows platforms.

Answer (score 5):

What about [**`ERROR_MESSAGE`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190358%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) ?

See also : [**Retrieving Error Information in Transact-SQL**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179495%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

And, from PHP (as your question is tagged `php`), take a look at :

- [**`mssql_get_last_message`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-get-last-message.php)
- [**`PDO::errorInfo`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php)

Depending on the API you're using to access your MS SQL Server database, of course.

Comment: ERROR_MESSAGE() requries sql:TRY..CATCH blocks and php:mssql_get_last_message() returns only the last line of an error, so in above example I get only "The statement has been terminated." (which is much less important information then that the first part about duplicate key).

Answer (score 0):

With the [sqlsrv extension module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee229551%28v=SQL.10%29.aspx) you can use [sqlsrv_errors( [int $errorsAndOrWarnings] )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296200%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but the solution must work on Windows and Linux platform. I will include that information in my question.

Comment: Is patching the mssql module an option?

Comment: Yes, how and what would I path?